# Creating DC charts dynamically

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I am having trouble creating charts dynamically in that i need to create new chart variable names on the fly

How do i pass dynamically created chart variable to generate charts with?

currently with the code below different charts are created but all have the same name... that being "chartname" i need pass them unique names dynamically somehow.

Cheers Bruce

```
var chartcount = 0;
var chartname = "chart" + chartcount.toString();
var chartid = "#chart" + chartcount.toString();  
var chartname = dc.barChart(chartid);   

// chart0
chartname
                .width(100)
                .height(100)
                .margins({ top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 35, left: 35 })
                .transitionDuration(250)....


var chartcount++;
var chartname = "chart" + chartcount.toString();
var chartid = "#chart" + chartcount.toString();  
var chartname = dc.barChart(chartid);

// chart1
chartname
                .width(100)
                .height(100)
                .margins({ top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 35, left: 35 })
                .transitionDuration(250)....


var chartcount++;
var chartname = "chart" + chartcount.toString();
var chartid = "#chart" + chartcount.toString();  
var chartname = dc.barChart(chartid);  

// chart2
chartname
                .width(100)
                .height(100)
                .margins({ top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 35, left: 35 })
                .transitionDuration(250)....
```

Comment: Please don't cross-post questions. [I answered on the users group.](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/dc-js-user-group/YM1myXkyLzY/7pUMmv2LDwAJ)

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're overwriting variables.

This should work:

```
var charts = []
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  charts[i] = dc.barChart('#chart' + i)
  charts[i]
    .width(100)
    .height(100)
    .margins({ top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 35, left: 35 })
    .transitionDuration(250)
}
```

Comment: Exactly what i needed.